# Cloudflare is blocking Bingbot

Tags: cloudflare, bing-webmaster-tools, bingbot, firewall

When I check BingWebmaster and use "Fetch as BingBot" then Bing is able to crawl that particular URL of my site. However, when I use SiteScan tool, then I am getting 4xx error. (SiteScan tool shows where we need on-page SEO improvements and that's why it is very important that SiteScan tool works.)

Then I tried TechnicalSEO tool to fetch&render and I did the test as follows for Bingbot useragent:

- Fetch & Render Tool link: https://technicalseo.com/tools/fetch-render/
- Pre Rendering Testing Tool link: https://technicalseo.com/tools/pre-rendering/
- Check for URL: https://www.playerauctions.com/osrs-gold/

and then found that CloudFlare forbids Bingbot useragent and results into HTTP 403 response.

```
HTTP/2 403 
date: Thu, 06 Aug 2020 01:46:22 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
set-cookie: __cfduid=d3f73e32abc0f9b1a8717b943883ee1b41596678382; expires=Sat, 05-Sep-20 01:46:22 GMT; path=/; domain=.playerauctions.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
cache-control: max-age=15
expires: Thu, 06 Aug 2020 01:46:37 GMT
x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN
cf-request-id: 04630bbbc4000002c02a114200000001
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: 5be51572dbc202c0-SEA
content-encoding: gzip
```

- I reached out to Bing helpcenter and they said check with your Network team.
- Network team said they couldn't find anything at CloudFlare which is blocking Bingbot.

I have checked posts on CloudFlare Forum on [Bingbot not able to access to my site](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/bingbot-not-able-to-access-to-my-site/183224), [Cloudflare bing bot block](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/cloudflare-bing-bot-block/161350) and [Bingbot blocked](https://community.cloudflare.com/t/bingbot-blocked/38087) however none of them works.

So what should I do to fix this problem?

Comment: I can confirm that your site is not available to Bingbot by using the following command line to fetch it:  `curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)' --head 'https://www.playerauctions.com/osrs-gold/'`  That gets a 403 error with the message "This website is using a security service to protect itself from online attacks. The action you just performed triggered the security solution. There are several actions that could trigger this block including submitting a certain word or phrase, a SQL command or malformed data."

Comment: I see.. so the client has a cloudflare firewall, so that means cloudflare itself blocking Bingbots, right?

Comment: I think it is cloudflare blocking Bingbot.  It could also be the origin server, but I think that cloudflare is more likely.   What rules are enabled on the firewall?   I have a domain hosted on cloudflare that just redirects.  I can fetch it with Bingbot just fine and get the redirect:  `curl -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)' --head 'https://attesoro.com'`  That domain just has the default Firewall rules -- the five "managed rules" to prevent different types of "floods" which cannot be disabled.

Comment: Let me check with network person again. By the way, which tool to use to execute curl command? i wil study that and do some experiments.

Comment: Curl is an open source command line application for fetching websites:  https://curl.haxx.se/  It can be installed on Windows, Mac, or Linux.

Comment: alright, thank you very much.

Comment: thanks, I tried copy-pasting that exact same command, and getting this message (uploaded screenshot on IMGUR): https://imgur.com/0w28EIe

Comment: It looks like Windows command line doesn't interpret single quotes.   Try switching the single quotes (`'`) to double quotes (`"`) in that command.   The user agent has to be passed as a single argument and from the error message, it appears that the parts of it are each getting passed separately.   i'm on Linux and don't have Windows, so I can't test it for you on Windows.

Comment: I see... okay. I’ll copy paste the error message from here and show it to network engineer. She is still claiming that everything is fine at firewall, so I’ll show her thi evidence. Thank you so much for your time, Stephen. This is very helpful.

Comment: I reached out to CloudFlare support and they suggested some solutions, that too is not working, so trying to figure out with their help documents.

Comment: Finally updated configuration at Cloudflare and then it worked like a charm! Thank you very much for the help :)

Comment: Can you add an answer saying exactly which settings at cloudflare got changed? It would help other people that come across this question in the future.

Comment: Yep sure. That would be my pleasure. I’ll do it on Monday

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We found out that not only CloudFlare, but also other services on CloudFlare were blocking BingBot.

Finally we allowed `Bing user-agent Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)` in Firewall settings and also added another rule to by-pass other default rules in WAF when the user-agent is Bingbot.

It may vary as per individual configurations, so suggesting to refer to CloudFlare FireWall Rules https://developers.cloudflare.com/firewall/cf-firewall-rules/actions/