# Bingbot issues and crawling my website root domain

Tags: web-crawlers, bing, bingbot

I seem to have this issue with a few different website's but bing is unable to crawl (or fetch the pages).

I have done a cURL via windows and it connected properly however every URL live inspection errors out. Robots.txt inspector only sometimes works but I have been able to submit sitemap's.

I have contacted my hosting company and they say that Bing isn't blocked yet Bing is saying their bots are being blocked. Does anyone have anything i can try to help resolve this?

I have tried disabling all plugins and still no luck.

Also google is able to crawl and index the website with no issue.

Comment: Troubleshooting questions that [only could apply to your site](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) are really not a good fit for this site. We also can't answer this definitively without knowing a lot more details about your site and its hosting environment. You'll need to work with your hosting company - perhaps looking at the error logs for your sever might help as well, though it sounds like a firewall issue.

Comment: yep no worries.

Comment: Make sure you're using the Bingbot's user-agent when using `cURL` as detailed in this question [here](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/130864/cloudflare-is-blocking-bingbot), and if you're similarly using a CDN, disable its proxying or put it in "Development Mode" and try fetching with Bing again.

Comment: cURL gave me
C:\Users\TEST>curl -A "Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; bingbot/2.0; +http://www.bing.com/bingbot.htm)" --head "https://www.skylabels.com.au"
HTTP/1.1 301 Moved Permanently
Connection: Keep-Alive
Keep-Alive: timeout=5, max=100
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.29
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
x-redirect-by: WordPress
location: https://skylabels.com.au/
date: Tue, 07 Jun 2022 01:04:07 GMT
server: LiteSpeed
alt-svc: h3=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-29=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q050=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q046=":443"; ma=2592000, h3-Q043=":443"; ma=2592000, quic=":443"; ma=2592000; v="43,46"